# Как с помощью JS закрыть текущую вкладку браузера?

Tags: javascript, javascript-events

Здравствуйте. Подобный вопрос уже был, но он не дал решения. Может быть, сейчас повезёт больше. Сразу скажу, я новичок в JS.
Нужно, чтобы по клику на кнопку закрывалась текущая вкладка.

```
var close_btn = document.getElementById('close');
close_btn.onclick = function(){
window.open("index.html", "_self");
window.close();
}
```

срабатывает только в Chrome. В остальных браузерах - нет. Вроде как в целях безопасности .close() не выполняется.
Посоветуйте решение, пожалуйста.

Comment: Решения нету, в целях безопасности javascript не может закрыть вкладку. Исключение - если javascript  открывал эту вкладку, тогда может.

Comment: window.open("index.html", "_self");

не является ли это открытием вкладки с  помощью JS ?

Comment: Является. Вот после открытия новой вкладки через `window.open`, эту вкладку вы сможете закрыть. Например `var newWin = window.open(...); newWin.close()`.

Comment: ``var close_btn = document.getElementById('close_btn');
close_btn.onclick = function(){var newWin = window.open("index.html", "_self", "");
 newWin.close();
};``

Так? Опять же, срабатывает только в Chrome. В FF вкладка перезагружается, но не закрывается.

Comment: Еще раз. Вы *не сможете* закрыть окно в js. Допустим, у вас есть две страницы, "родитель" и "ребенок". Родитель открывает ребенка. Родитель может закрыть ребенка. Ребенок сам себя закрыть не может. Если вы пытаетесь открыть родителя в ребенке, то родитель пропадает, а ребенок сам себя закрыть не может!